# Why do the button functions not work after changing the grid size?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

When running the program for the first time the button functions work as expected.

But after changing the grid size via range slider the button functions all do not work anymore...

Why do the button functions not work anymore as soon as changing the grid size?
What is missing in my algorithm?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

```js
"use strict";

const divContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
const btnsContainer = document.querySelector(".buttons");
const btnBlack = document.createElement("button");
const btnGreyScale = document.createElement("button");
const btnRgb = document.createElement("button");
const btnErase = document.createElement("button");
const btnShake = document.createElement("button");

const input = document.querySelector("input");
const outputs = document.querySelectorAll("output");
let slider = document.getElementById("gridSize");

const body = document.querySelector("body");
document.body.ondragstart = () => { return false };

function createGrid(col, rows) {
  for (let i = 0; i < (col * rows); i++) {
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      divContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${col}, 1fr)`;
      divContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`;
      divContainer.appendChild(div).classList.add("box");
  }
}
createGrid(50,50);

let isDrawing = false;
window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    isDrawing = true;
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    isDrawing = false;
});

function paintBlack() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnBlack.textContent = "Black";
  btnBlack.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = "#000"};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnBlack).classList.add("btn", "blackBtn");
}
paintBlack();

function paintGreyScale() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnGreyScale.textContent = "Grey";
  btnGreyScale.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let grayScale = `rgb(${randNum},${randNum},${randNum})`;
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = grayScale};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnGreyScale).classList.add("btn", "greyBtn");
}
paintGreyScale();

function paintRgb() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnRgb.textContent = "Rainbow";
  btnRgb.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      const rgb = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = rgb};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnRgb).classList.add("btn", "rainbowBtn");
}
paintRgb();

function erase() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnErase.textContent = "Erase";
  btnErase.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = "#FFF"};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnErase).classList.add("btn", "eraseBtn");
}
erase();

function clearCanvas() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnShake.textContent = "Shake it!";
  btnShake.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF");
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnShake).classList.add("btn", "clearCanvasBtn", "shake");
}
clearCanvas();

btnShake.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);

input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  for (let output of outputs) {
    output.innerText = input.value;
  }
})

function modifyGridSize() {
  let boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  boxes.forEach(box => box.remove());
  createGrid(slider.value, slider.value);
}

slider.addEventListener("mouseup", modifyGridSize);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1488CC, #2B32B2);
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "buttons container";
  grid-auto-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.container {
  width: 515px;
  height: 515px;
  display: grid;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
}

.box {
  border: .5px solid #808080;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family : inherit;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
}

.btn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px;
}

.blackBtn {
  background: #000;
  color: #4C4C4C;
}

.greyBtn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #BDC3C7, #2C3E50);
}

.rainbowBtn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
}

.eraseBtn {
  background: #FFF;
}

.clearCanvasBtn {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.shake {
  animation: shake .5s linear 1;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

#wrapper label {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.gridDimension {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="range"] {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/etchAsketch.css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <main id="wrapper">
        <div class="buttons">
          <label for="gridSize">Select Grid Size:</label>
          <div class="gridDimension"><output>50</output> x <output>50</output></div>
          <input id="gridSize" type="range" name="gridSize" value="50" step="1" min="1" max="100">
        </div>
        <div class="container"></div>
      </main>

    <script src="etchAsketch.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is happening because the modifyGridSize is removing all the boxes and so it will remove the eventListeners too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just moved all event logic under the creategrid and it works

```js
"use strict";

const divContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
const btnsContainer = document.querySelector(".buttons");
const btnBlack = document.createElement("button");
const btnGreyScale = document.createElement("button");
const btnRgb = document.createElement("button");
const btnErase = document.createElement("button");
const btnShake = document.createElement("button");

const input = document.querySelector("input");
const outputs = document.querySelectorAll("output");
let slider = document.getElementById("gridSize");

const body = document.querySelector("body");
document.body.ondragstart = () => { return false };

function createGrid(col, rows) {
  for (let i = 0; i < (col * rows); i++) {
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      divContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${col}, 1fr)`;
      divContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`;
      divContainer.appendChild(div).classList.add("box");
  }
  paintBlack();
  paintGreyScale();
  paintRgb();
  erase();
  clearCanvas();
}


let isDrawing = false;
window.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    isDrawing = true;
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    isDrawing = false;
});

function paintBlack() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnBlack.textContent = "Black";
  btnBlack.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = "#000"};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnBlack).classList.add("btn", "blackBtn");
}


function paintGreyScale() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnGreyScale.textContent = "Grey";
  btnGreyScale.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let grayScale = `rgb(${randNum},${randNum},${randNum})`;
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = grayScale};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnGreyScale).classList.add("btn", "greyBtn");
}


function paintRgb() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnRgb.textContent = "Rainbow";
  btnRgb.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      const rgb = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = rgb};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnRgb).classList.add("btn", "rainbowBtn");
}


function erase() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnErase.textContent = "Erase";
  btnErase.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener("mousemove", function () {
      if (isDrawing) {this.style.background = "#FFF"};
    }))
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnErase).classList.add("btn", "eraseBtn");
}


function clearCanvas() { 
  const boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  btnShake.textContent = "Shake it!";
  btnShake.addEventListener("click", function () {
    boxes.forEach(box => box.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF");
  })
  btnsContainer.appendChild(btnShake).classList.add("btn", "clearCanvasBtn", "shake");
}


btnShake.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);

input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  for (let output of outputs) {
    output.innerText = input.value;
  }
})

function modifyGridSize() {
  let boxes = divContainer.querySelectorAll(".box");
  boxes.forEach(box => box.remove());
  createGrid(slider.value, slider.value);
}

slider.addEventListener("mouseup", modifyGridSize);
createGrid(50,50);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1488CC, #2B32B2);
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "buttons container";
  grid-auto-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.container {
  width: 515px;
  height: 515px;
  display: grid;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
}

.box {
  border: .5px solid #808080;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-family : inherit;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
}

.btn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px;
}

.blackBtn {
  background: #000;
  color: #4C4C4C;
}

.greyBtn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #BDC3C7, #2C3E50);
}

.rainbowBtn {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, orange , yellow, green, cyan, blue, violet);
}

.eraseBtn {
  background: #FFF;
}

.clearCanvasBtn {
  background: #FF0000;
}

.shake {
  animation: shake .5s linear 1;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

#wrapper label {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.gridDimension {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="range"] {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/etchAsketch.css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <main id="wrapper">
        <div class="buttons">
          <label for="gridSize">Select Grid Size:</label>
          <div class="gridDimension"><output>50</output> x <output>50</output></div>
          <input id="gridSize" type="range" name="gridSize" value="50" step="1" min="1" max="100">
        </div>
        <div class="container"></div>
      </main>

    <script src="etchAsketch.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```